# XPAges Validating a combo Box

Tags: validation, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have created a standard xp:comboBox and populated it with a list of companies so the combo box values looks something like this:

- Select A Company -
  Company a
  Company B
  etc

so the initial value for the combo is - Select A Company - so I tried creating a Custom Validator based on the example given in Mastering XPages pg 116

```
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:customValidator>
        <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (value == "- Select A Company -"){
    return new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Select a Company from the List Provided.");
}}]]>
        </xp:this.validate>
    </xp:customValidator>
</xp:this.validators>
```

The validator does not seem to fire. I have several other simple required firlds and they all work as expected. Is this a comboBox issue or have I missed something in the code?

Added this to an input box and it does not work either:

```
<xp:this.validators>
    <xp:customValidator>
        <xp:this.validate><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (value != "ABC"){
    return new javax.faces.application.FacesMessage("Value Must be ABC.");
}}]]>
        </xp:this.validate>
    </xp:customValidator>
</xp:this.validators>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom validators are only fired if a required validator is defined.
If you want a "required" validator being fired you just need to add another formula value item with a value of

```
return "";
```

as the first value item in your definition.

Comment: Not necessarily intuitively obvious and all the documentation that I have read says nothing about that but then .....
Thanks Oliver